# Noughts and crosses python drawing the board

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started teaching myself python 3.2 (or attempting to). I think i have all the basics so i decided to try and build what a lot of people have told me is the easiest game to start with, 0's and X's. I am trying to draw the board with a list of lists, i want to use a variable N that will be passed into the method to determine the size of the board N*N.

I have searched everywhere how to do this but all i can find is people who have coded it with a set value of rows and columns. i want to make it changeable so i can go on and reuse my code to try checkers and perhaps chess.

Please can someone help me, it will be much appreciated.

Thanks, Dave.

Comment: Is this like pigs and porcupines?

Comment: Ummm.... look at `input` to ask for something as a string and `int` to turn that into a integer... The next question you may well have have is why your list of lists don't work as you expect :)./ Seriously though, if you search around SO for noughts and crosses or tic tac toe you'll find loads of sample questions and answers to help you relating building boards, limited AI, accepting input, etc...

Answer (score 1):

There are more concise ways of writing this in Python, but this might be the easiest to understand as a novice:

```
N=3
tictac = []

for i in range(N):
    row = []
    for i in range(N):
        row.append('O')
    tictac.append(row)

for row in tictac:
    print row
```

Comment: Thanks John thats pretty helpful. Im not sure why when i use 3 as the n value it just draws "O   O   O" i would have expected it to be three rown of this on top of each other :/